# Converting Bit String to Double

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have used `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` and `Long.toBinaryString` to convert a `double` value to a `String` of `bits`. However, I am trying to find the methods to convert a `String` of `bits` back to a `double`. `Double.longBitsToDouble` will convert a `Long` representation of bits to `double`, but I have been having trouble finding a method to convert the `String` of `bits` to a `long` representation of `bits`.

Any help with this question would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time in reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
long n = ...
String s = Long.toBinaryString(n);
```

you use

```
long reconstructed = Long.parseLong(s, 2);
```

to reconstruct the long.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The combination of Long.parseLong and Double.longBitsToDouble has allowed me to convert the String of bits back into a double. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`Long.valueOf(String s,int radix)` should give you a long from a string of bits in base *radix*, and `Double.longBitsToDouble(long l)` will give you the initial double back.